# monthly cron job specific day ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have the following crontab scripts on Ubuntu 16.04. Will this work as intended by running on first Wednesday/Tuesday of the month at 3 and 5 AM?

```
0 3 * * 3 [ $(date +\%d) -le 07 ] && sudo sh /usr/local/letsencrypt /autorenew.sh >/dev/null 2>&1

0 5 * * 2 [ $(date +\%d) -le 07 ] && sudo find /var/log -type f -name "*.gz" -exec rm -f {} \; >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

The comparison you specify will work, yes.

As a technicality, discarding all output and errors is extremely ill-advised at least until you have debugged your scripts.

`sudo sh /usr/local/letsencrypt /autorenew.sh` looks weird but if `letsencrypt` is indeed a `sh` script which lacks a proper shebang and/or execute permission, and accepts an argument `/autorenew.sh` for whatever purpose, maybe it's correct.  Or maybe you have one or more typos and should leave out the `sh`.